# Aeson parse JSON and use State to keep it in memory

Tags: json, haskell, state

I have a "settings" file in my Haskell learning project. It's a JSON file with a basic structure for defining some settings. The settings are now parsed every time when I try to grab something from it. It's reparsed everytime. So I figured I have to keep some `State` for it that it's been parsed and available.

```
 parseSettings :: IO Settings
 parseSettings = do
    settingsContent <- B.readFile settingsFile
    let settings = decode settingsContent :: Maybe Settings
    case settings of
        Just s  -> return s
        Nothing -> error "Couldn't parse settings file"
```

This is the `getSetting` I am using atm:

```
getSetting :: (Settings -> a) -> IO a
getSetting f = do
    settings <- parseSettings
    return (f settings)
```

Now instead of calling `parseSettings`, I want to actually do something stateful so that I don't have to reparse the settings file everytime I call `getSetting`. Can anyone recommend me blogposts/articles or any pointers at how to use the `State` monad for this? (or if there is a simpler way, I'd prefer that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `StateT` you can do

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Applicative

type App = StateT (Maybe Settings) IO

parseSettings :: IO Settings
parseSettings = undefined  -- Keep your implementation

reloadSettings :: App ()
reloadSettings = do
    settings <- liftIO parseSettings
    put $ Just settings

getSetting :: (Settings -> a) -> App a
getSetting f = get >>= maybe (reloadSettings >> getSetting f) (return . f)
```

Then you can use this as

```
data Settings = Settings
    { hostname :: String
    , port :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

sendRequest :: Request -> App Response
sendRequest request = do
    h <- getSetting hostname
    p <- getSetting port
    liftIO $ do
        hndl <- connect h p
        sendRequest hndl request
        readResponse hndl
```

And you can run it with

```
runApp :: App a -> IO a
runApp app = evalStateT app Nothing
```

This allows you to worry about parsing the settings the first time you call `getSetting`, and it'll use the current settings after that.  If you need to reload the settings just use `reloadSettings`, and all subsequent commands will use the new settings.

Note that if you want your settings to always be static throughout the application, it's much better to use the `Reader` monad as Petr shows.  This separates the loading of your settings from the running of your application, it has to occur in a two-step process.  If you do want to allow the settings to change throughout the application then the `State` monad is necessary.

Comment: I have it working the way you implemented it (with `runApp`), but I don't understand why the `App` type has the `Maybe` in it's definition. What is the `Maybe` for?

Comment: @tolgap If you didn't use `Maybe` then you would have to have a valid `Settings` value to feed into `evalStateT app`, I'm using it here to indicate that the settings may or may not exist, but so long as you're using `getSetting`, the settings will get loaded the first time, and after that it'll just the `Just settings` that are stored as the state.  Essentially, it's so that the application can load the settings inside `App` instead of in `main` before the application is run.

Comment: Ah I get it, the `Maybe` is used to check if it's been parsed or not. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Unless you need to modify the configuration during the run of your program, it makes more sense to use [`Reader`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#t:Reader). You could express your functions using the `Reader` (or `ReaderT`, if you need other monads in your stack, like `IO` etc.) monad and then something like

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  s <- parseSettings
  runReader program s
```

Comment: I actually like @bheklilr 's implementation more, as it sits closer to my current implementation. But I will surely keep the `Reader` in my mind.

Comment: @tolgap As the edit just made says, `Reader` is a good choice if you want your settings to be static, but `State` is necessary if you want to be able to change your settings while the application is running.  Use the tool best suited to your application, and if you're always accessing it through `getSetting` then you won't have trouble converting between `Reader` or `State` for your application, you'll just have to change the `App` type and the implementation of `getSetting`